# jQuery: Cannot execute code after switching event and class of div

Tags: jquery, events, button, handler

I faced an issue that if I click on an HTML element and change his class, event is not switched to the new class. After searched I found that I must use on() and stopPropagation().

Now I see that event is switch, however code is not execute.
Event viewer in firebug shows which element is use click event. And when I click on  this row in firebug is blinking. So It seems that event work but why code is not execute ?

```
  $(function(){
  $(".on").on("click",function(e){
  $(this).attr("class","off").html("off");
  e.stopPropagation();
  });

  $(".off").on("click",function(){
  $(this).attr("class","on").html("on");

   });
```

});

html is simple just on by click it must change to 'off' and back again(by click).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off might not be binded properly (those elements doesn't have this clas when on wa run ) you suppose ro handle it like that:

```
$(function() {

  $(".parentOfOn").delegate('.on',"click",function(e){
  $(this).attr("class","off").html("off");
  e.stopPropagation();
  });

  $(".parentOfOff").delegate('.off',"click",function(){
  $(this).attr("class","on").html("on");

   });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the "toggleClass" api instead.

http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Answer (score 0):

Might be better to use toggleClass if its just going to be on and off

[toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Answer (score 0):

Just like this maybe:

http://jsfiddle.net/LrGmH/

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on("click",".on,.off", function (e) {
        $(this).toggleClass("on off").html($(this).attr('class'));
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, you would probably be better off using the toggleClass api.

I believe your original code is not working because when the function is initially called, $(".0ff") does not return any valid objects, so the click handlers are not correctly applied. Try moving the off click handler inside the click function for the on state like this:

Edit 1:
Original code was not working correctly. Updated code and provided jsfiddle.

```
$(function(){
  bindOnClick();
});


function bindOnClick(){
    $(".on").on("click",function(e){
        $(".on").unbind("click");
        $(this).attr("class","off").html("off");
        bindOffClick();

        e.stopPropagation();
    });
}

function bindOffClick(){
    $(".off").on("click",function(){
        $(".off").unbind("click");
        $(this).attr("class","on").html("on");
        bindOnClick();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q6R3q/)

Comment: In your code script changes "on" to "off" than to "on" end stops execute.  http://jsfiddle.net/dimaomni/6MNHP/

Comment: You are correct. I am updating my answer with working code and a link to the jsfiddle.